# Rolling sum where category values are replaced/updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, rolling-computation

I'm trying to get a rolling sum working where categories/groups Amount change at any given date - when the change happens *that* category's new value becomes apart of the rolling sum, but the previous value of that category is then ignored; so it's a rolling sum, but only based on the latest of each category (at that point in time).

Example data (SumAmount being the problem trying to solve)

```
txn_id | cust_id | trans_date |  Category | amount | SumAmount
-----------------------------------------------------------------
     1 |       1 |  2020-01-01|  Ball     |      5 |   5     --first tran so sum is 5
     2 |       1 |  2020-01-02|  Cup      |      5 |   10    --sum is 10 (ball=5,Cup=5)
     3 |       1 |  2020-01-03|  Ball     |      2 |   7     --sum is 7 (ball=2,Cup=5) 
     4 |       1 |  2020-02-04|  Ball     |      4 |   9     --sum is 9 (ball=4,Cup=5)
     5 |       1 |  2020-02-05|  Ball     |      1 |   6     --sum is 6 (ball=1,Cup=5)
     6 |       1 |  2020-02-06|  Cup      |      10|   11    --sum is 11(ball=1,Cup=10)
     7 |       1 |  2020-02-07|  Phone    |      5 |   16    --sum is 16(ball=1,Cup=10,Phone=5)
     8 |       1 |  2020-02-08|  Cup      |      5 |   11    --sum is 11(ball=1,Cup=5,Phone=5)
     9 |       1 |  2020-02-09|  Ball     |      5 |   15    --sum is 15(ball=5,Cup=5,Phone=5)
```

I've got this working within a cursor but wondering if SET based is possible

The cursor goes like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PriceHistory](@CustId int, @MaxPriceHistory decimal(16,2) Output)
create table #PriceHistory ( CategoryID uniqueidentifier, Amount decimal(16,2))

    declare pricehistory_cursor CURSOR FOR
    select CategoryID, Amount
    from mytable
    where CustId =@CustId
    order by trans_date;

    declare @CategoryID uniqueidentifier
    declare @Amount decimal(16,2)
    declare @CurrentTotal decimal(16,2)

    set @MaxPriceHistory = 0

    open pricehistory_cursor
    fetch next from pricehistory_cursor into @CategoryID, @Amount

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN 
           if (exists(select * from #PriceHistory where CategoryID = @CategoryID))
                  update #PriceHistory set Amount = @actualAmount where CategoryID = @CategoryID 
           else
                  insert into #PriceHistory(CategoryID,Amount) values (@CategoryID, @Amount)

           select @CurrentTotal = sum(Amount) from #PriceHistory

           if (@CurrentTotal > @MaxPriceHistory)
                  set @MaxPriceHistory = @CurrentTotal

           fetch next from pricehistory_cursor into @CategoryID, @Amount                 
    END

    close pricehistory_cursor
    deallocate pricehistory_cursor;
```

Ultimately, I'm looking for the Max SumAmount throughout the life of the transactions (column SumAmount in provided example), in which for this example it would be 16.

I get what the cursor is doing and I get why it works that way (replacing Amount for that certain Category if already exists (this is the bit I'm stumped on for SET based approach, how would I get the Cup amount of 5, when txn_id = 5 happens?), and summing it up along with all other latest category amounts made at that point in time), I just can't get my head around if it's possible to do with either some kind of recursive CTE or ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @lptr Well that's funky, never used JSON functions before. This is my bad for not stating data types, but does JSON function manage MONEY or DECIMALS? My Amount column is money not INT

Comment: just cast( .. as your datatype) instead of cast( as int).

Comment: @lptr Ooo looks like json_modify function doesn't do money datatype
"Argument data type money is invalid for argument 3 of json_modify function."
I'll have a dig around Google! :D

Comment: …and in general decimal might be a better choice than money..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is in a fresh new temporary table, that also means that the primary key doesn't have gaps.

That's a nice situation for a recursive CTE.

The query below keeps the latest amount for the balls, cups and phones.
Then the calculation of the sum simply depends on the category.

> ```
> WITH RCTE_BALL_CUP_PHONE AS
> (
>    SELECT txn_id, cust_id, trans_date, category, amount
>    , CASE WHEN category = 'Ball'  THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS NearestBallAmount
>    , CASE WHEN category = 'Cup'   THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS NearestCupAmount
>    , CASE WHEN category = 'Phone' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS NearestPhoneAmount
>    , amount AS SumAmount
>    FROM  #PriceHistory AS tmp
>    WHERE txn_id = 1
>
>    UNION ALL
>
>    SELECT tmp.txn_id, tmp.cust_id, tmp.trans_date, tmp.category, tmp.amount
>    , CASE WHEN tmp.category = 'Ball'  THEN tmp.amount ELSE c.NearestBallAmount END
>    , CASE WHEN tmp.category = 'Cup'   THEN tmp.amount ELSE c.NearestCupAmount END
>    , CASE WHEN tmp.category = 'Phone' THEN tmp.amount ELSE c.NearestPhoneAmount END
>    , CASE 
>      WHEN tmp.category = 'Ball'  THEN (tmp.amount + c.NearestCupAmount  + c.NearestPhoneAmount)
>      WHEN tmp.category = 'Cup'   THEN (tmp.amount + c.NearestBallAmount + c.NearestPhoneAmount)
>      WHEN tmp.category = 'Phone' THEN (tmp.amount + c.NearestCupAmount  + c.NearestBallAmount)
>      ELSE tmp.Amount
>      END
>    FROM RCTE_BALL_CUP_PHONE c
>    JOIN #PriceHistory AS tmp 
>      ON tmp.txn_id = c.txn_id + 1
> )
> SELECT txn_id, cust_id, trans_date, category, amount
> , SumAmount
> FROM RCTE_BALL_CUP_PHONE
> ORDER BY txn_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> txn_id | cust_id | trans_date | category | amount | SumAmount
> -----: | ------: | :--------- | :------- | -----: | --------:
>      1 |       1 | 2020-01-01 | Ball     |      5 |         5
>      2 |       1 | 2020-01-02 | Cup      |      5 |        10
>      3 |       1 | 2020-01-03 | Ball     |      2 |         7
>      4 |       1 | 2020-02-04 | Ball     |      4 |         9
>      5 |       1 | 2020-02-05 | Ball     |      1 |         6
>      6 |       1 | 2020-02-06 | Cup      |     10 |        11
>      7 |       1 | 2020-02-07 | Phone    |      5 |        16
>      8 |       1 | 2020-02-08 | Cup      |      5 |        11
>      9 |       1 | 2020-02-09 | Ball     |      5 |        15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e4905b2fc87a886c412c14ba6ca4526)*

For future reference sake, here's an adaption of lptr's awesome JSON method.
It'll work for more than 3 categories without having to change anything.

> ```
> with RCTE as
> (
>   select *, cast(concat('{"', category, '":', amount, '}') as varchar(max)) as j
>   from #PriceHistory t
>   where txn_id=1
>
>   union all
>
>   select t.*, cast(json_modify(cte.j, concat('$.', t.category), t.amount) as varchar(max))
>   from RCTE cte
>   join #PriceHistory t on t.txn_id = cte.txn_id+1
> )
> select txn_id, cust_id, trans_date, category, amount
> , (select sum(cast(value as int)) from openjson(j)) as SumAmount
> , j
> from RCTE
> order by txn_id
> ```

> ```
> txn_id | cust_id | trans_date | category | amount | SumAmount | j                            
> -----: | ------: | :--------- | :------- | -----: | --------: | :----------------------------
>      1 |       1 | 2020-01-01 | Ball     |      5 |         5 | {"Ball":5}                   
>      2 |       1 | 2020-01-02 | Cup      |      5 |        10 | {"Ball":5,"Cup":5}           
>      3 |       1 | 2020-01-03 | Ball     |      2 |         7 | {"Ball":2,"Cup":5}           
>      4 |       1 | 2020-02-04 | Ball     |      4 |         9 | {"Ball":4,"Cup":5}           
>      5 |       1 | 2020-02-05 | Ball     |      1 |         6 | {"Ball":1,"Cup":5}           
>      6 |       1 | 2020-02-06 | Cup      |     10 |        11 | {"Ball":1,"Cup":10}          
>      7 |       1 | 2020-02-07 | Phone    |      5 |        16 | {"Ball":1,"Cup":10,"Phone":5}
>      8 |       1 | 2020-02-08 | Cup      |      5 |        11 | {"Ball":1,"Cup":5,"Phone":5} 
>      9 |       1 | 2020-02-09 | Ball     |      5 |        15 | {"Ball":5,"Cup":5,"Phone":5}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this! Looks to be what I'm after, the category list could be into the 100's, so I'm guessing I'd have to build some dynamic table with those pre-listed, but it's defo something i can work with :)

Comment: @MrC  Thanks, and glad that it helps. Well, this works for 3 categories. But if you got a lot of categories then you really should consider using the awesome JSON trick that lptr added in the comments. It'll work for any number of categories. I tried it in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9a76da7926fd7cf239011bec6d550d79)